# Linking DataGridView with Crystal Report problem C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, crystal-reports

I have a problem with my C# project, where I want to print my dataGridView through Crystal Reports. Connected the Crystal Report with my table (I am not using all columns from the table) and had the design done, but when I run the program, the report doesnt show the data. I've tried many different ways of doing dataGridView to crystal report but while I got no error, the data simply didnt show. THe code is below:

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.printDataGridView.Rows)
        {

            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

            if (item.DataBoundItem != null)
            {
                dr = (DataRow)((DataRowView)item.DataBoundItem).Row;
                dt.ImportRow(dr);
            }
        }
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);


        ReportNabavka crypt = new ReportNabavka();
        crypt.Load("C..."); \\
        crypt.SetDataSource(ds);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crypt;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Also, the dataGridView shows the data that i want (in this case, the printDataGridView)
Thank you

Comment: Looks like your grid is already data-bound. Why don't you just use it's `DataSource` property instead of looping over the rows? Regardless, I suggest you try contriving a dataset and see if that works. If it does then work out acquiring the dataset from the grid.

Comment: I have tried that, but error message said that the column Item already exists in the DataTable. Also, when I do it this way, then the DataTable preview in debugger shows that the table has all the rows needed but no columns/Data. While the original DataSet shows all the data needed.